# Can I use segues with designated initializers of view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboard, segue

I am new to storyboards and I have set up a segue from a button to a view controller. This view controller is of a custom subclass `SFListViewController`, which has a designated initializer `initWithList:`.

Using the designated initializer is the only way to correctly initialize the view controller. However, when using segues the designated initializer won't be called (obviously).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show List"]) {
    SFListViewController *listViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    // ????
  }
}
```

How can I make the segue call the designated initializer when performed?

Comment: +1 That's a good question, I've had a similar problem when letting Interface Builder instantiate objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible since the storyboard framework simply calls `alloc` and `init` on the class you define in Interfacebuilder. Additionally the segue's `destinationViewController` attribute is read-only so you couldn't simply replace the existing ViewController either.

The only way to use Storyboarding would probably be to create a wrapper-class that internally instantiates the `SFListViewController` with the desired attributes and then functions as a proxy object and thus propagates `viewDid***` and `viewWill***`-methods to the wrapped class and also returning the wrapped VC's view in a readonly `view` property... You get the idea.

Generally there are a number of alternative ways to initialize a `UIViewController` in such a case:

1. There is an option to specify "User defined runtime Attributes" which could be used for initialisation.
2. Override the `prepareForSegue:` method, like you tried, in your root ViewController and do "post-alloc-init-initialisation" there.
3. If worst comes worst, you could fall back to an `IBAction` in order to be able to initialize the ViewController yourself.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** I can verify that the Proxy-Approach works since I just came across a similar problem with `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` where this approach worked nicely. Since we've set up the thing in our story board please note that you have to use `awakeFromNib` in order to do initial configuration (instead of some `init` method).

This is the code for my wrapper class:

```
#import "PeoplePickerViewControllerWrapper.h"

@implementation PeoplePickerViewControllerWrapper

@synthesize ppvc = _ppvc;  // This is the object I'm proxying (The proxyee so to speak)
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
        self.ppvc = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init ];
        self.ppvc.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        self.ppvc.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
        self.ppvc.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    [self.ppvc loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.ppvc viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.ppvc viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.ppvc viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

-(UIView *)view{
    return self.ppvc.view;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self.ppvc viewDidUnload];
}
```