# Segue to ABPersonViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, abpersonviewcontroller

I am trying to segue to a `ABPersonViewController` from a button in the Storyboard.
But if I do that the screen is completely black.

If I use a `IBAction` for the button and use the following code it works:

```
ABPersonViewController *person = [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:person animated:YES];
```

Why is that?  am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I found a work around but I don't think this is a proper way to do it. I subclassed `ABPersonViewControlle`r and overrode the `initWithCoder` method with the following:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    return self;

}
```

Comment: Did you add the action from triggered segues for the particular button? How are you presenting the view controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display ABPeoplePickerNavigationController using storyboard segue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953080/display-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-using-storyboard-segue)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using storyboards you should should name the segue you are using and then this in your IBAction:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"abPersonViewControllerSegue" sender:self];
```

This way you do not even need to manually call alloc/init. Then in your prepareForSegue you could set any attributes:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"abPersonViewControllerSegue"]) 
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setAttribute:@"whatever you want"];
        ...      
    }
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You don't set the displayedPerson property ...

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) ABRecordRef displayedPerson
```

Comment: this is not the problem. If you don't set it you just get an empty ABPersonViewController. But with Storyboard I just get a black screen.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Storyboard, why do you still call [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init]?The Storyboard will handle the creation and pushing of the ABPersonViewController(if you specified Push action for the segue). As long as you control dragged from the Button to the ABPersonViewController in story board, you do not need to write a single line of code. If you control dragged from the view controller that contains the button, then you should be calling performSegue to trigger the segue(you need to set the identifier for the segue in this case) that adds the ABPersonViewController to the navigation controller.