# Custom text over ABPeoplePickerNavigationController "All Contacts" header

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

In Apple Calendar app, if you inviting people to event you will see specific text under header:

[image: Apple Calendar]

In my app I'm using people picker too. I would like to add a custom hint for a user over *All Contacts* header.

[image: My app]

IBAction for a button:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
self.addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[self.addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
self.addressBookController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                                                  nil];
[self presentViewController:self.addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

All delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark Address Book Delegate

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
[self.addressBookController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
CFStringRef currentPhoneValue = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, identifier);

// Some custom code working with a phone number

return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to customize the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` anyhow.
You can create a `UIViewController` with a `UILabel` (with your hint for users) and a container view; then embed `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` into the container view. This can be easily achieved via Interface Builder and also can be done programmatically, see the [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) section in UIViewController's Class Reference Overview.

#### Update

Unfortunately it seems that `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` can't be added directly to the Storyboard; please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956811/1310204) to see a workaround.